# Swift: Adding SSL key to URLRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, swift4, xcode9

I'm trying to make a URLRequest but I need to add SSL key and password to the request but I haven't found any example of how to accomplish this.

This is my requests:

```
func requestFactory(request:URLRequest, completion:@escaping (_ data:Data?)->Void){  
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, urlRequestResponse, error) in

    if error != nil{
        completion(data)
    }
})
task.resume()
```

}

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 4**
Assuming you have purchased yourself an SSL certificate, Google how to convert your SSL bundle certificate (.crt file) to .der format using OpenSSL in Terminal. Locate the .der file you created in your file system and drag it into your project folder in Xcode. Next, go to your project root and under Build Phases, click on the drop down list 'Copy Bundle Resources' and click the + button to add the .der file to the resource list.

Next you will need to make a class that implements URLSessionDelegate (in my case I called it URLSessionPinningDelegate) and when you formulate your URLSession call, you will pass in this class as the delegate. 
You should have a look at how to implement SSL certificate pinning for instructions on how to implement this class. This site [here](https://www.bugsee.com/blog/ssl-certificate-pinning-in-mobile-applications/) has a perfect and functioning explanation of how to do that.

Below is an example of how to set up the session and task. The password will be passed in the Header of URLRequest when you call request.setValue so check out that documentation too. This should get you started once you've figured out SSL certificate pinning and have set up your backend to authenticate your user's password and also set up trust for your client-side certificate.

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com") { // Your SSL server URL
var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
let password = "" // Your password value
request.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: password)

let session = URLSession(
configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral,
delegate: URLSessionPinningDelegate(),
delegateQueue: nil)
```

With the added session and request parameters your code would look like this:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription): \(error!)")
            } else if data != nil {
                if let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                    print("Received data:\n\(str)")
                } else {
                    print("Unable to convert data to text")
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()
```